# C language - using fscanf for a long text file

Tags: c, printf, clang

i want to read a text file like this:

```
Soldiers in some part of empire are not doing so well. We could cut funds by reducing their numbers.
Yes, reduce their numbers.
-5
0
5
No, we need them.
0
0
-10
```

i wrote a structure for saving loaded data, but it's not working...

```
FILE * Fchoice = fopen(Addresses, "r+");

fscanf(Fchoice ,"%[^\n]s\n%[^\n]s\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%[^\n]s%d\n%d\n%d",
        TmpProblem.question,               // char[]
        TmpProblem.choices[0].what,        // char[]
        &TmpProblem.choices[0].people,     // int
        &TmpProblem.choices[0].court,      // int
        &TmpProblem.choices[0].treasury,   // int
        TmpProblem.choices[1].what,        // char[]
        &TmpProblem.choices[1].people,     // int
        &TmpProblem.choices[1].court,      // int
        &TmpProblem.choices[1].treasury    // int
        );
```

after printing data that i have loaded, it's just loaded first line of text...
can you guys, debug this ?

Comment: Note: `%[^\n]s` is not a valid format specifier but a hybrid of `%s` and `%[^\n]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^\n]s` is not a format specifier, what you want is `[^\n]\n`.

Where `[^\n]` reads until `\n` occurs.

---

Thus replace

```
"%[^\n]s\n%[^\n]s%d\n%d\n%d\n%[^\n]s%d\n%d\n%d"
```

with

```
"%[^\n]\n%[^\n]\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%[^\n]\n%d\n%d\n%d"
```

Comment: Be careful about the `\n` after `%[^\n]`; it is white space, so it means read any amount of white space up to the next character that is not white space (and a blank in the same place would mean the same, and so would a tab).  And be very cautious about trailing white space in a `scanf()` string — they are appalling for the UX if a user might be typing the input data.